# How to calculate median of unsorted values

Tags: excel, vba, median

Hello is there a way of calculate median of unsorted values in row in excel or with VBA?
Or maybe som way how to arrange values with VBA in row?

Thank you

I only found how to sort values in column with sort VBA function

Comment: The MEDIAN() function?

Answer (score 0):

In vba code:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim result
'Set r = Range("C:C") 'Column C
Set r = Range("3:3") 'Row 3
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(r)
```